# Is there a way to delete all lines of text from a .txt file using StreamReader/Writer?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I am using C# with Unity.
I have a text file in my assets that is updated by a void function via StreamWriter. I want to remove all lines of text from the file (making it blank) upon the execution of another function. Is there a way to do this? I've had difficulty finding an appropriate method in the documentation.

Comment: It is just [_File.WriteAllText(filename, "");_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-6.0)

Comment: _File.WriteAllText_ will of course only work if the respective file is not held open by some other Stream/StreamWriter or some such in your own or other programs. Otherwise it will throw a hissy fit, i mean exception, complaining that it can't overwrite the file because someone still has their grubby fingers on it...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace thanks, this seems to be the issue i was running into.

Comment: Frederik van Lierde's answer
worked the best for my purpose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your streamwriter contructor, set the parameter append to false
When you open the txt file, you will see that only the next text is available.

```
string fileName = @"test.txt";
StreamWriter writer;
using (writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false)) { 
    writer.Write("new text");
}
```